# Data binding of user control doesn't respond

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to wrap my head around data binding, so I've made the following toy example:
user control xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Ex2.testUC"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Ex2"
             x:Name="testuc"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="150" d:DesignWidth="150">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Label Grid.Row="{Binding Path=Row, ElementName=testuc}"
               Grid.Column="{Binding Path=Col, ElementName=testuc}"
               Background="Red" Height="50" Width="50"/>
        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Background="Blue" Height="50" Width="50"/>
        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Background="Blue" Height="50" Width="50"/>
        <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Background="Blue" Height="50" Width="50"/>
        <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Background="Blue" Height="50" Width="50"/>
        <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Background="Blue" Height="50" Width="50"/>
        <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Background="Blue" Height="50" Width="50"/>
        <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Background="Blue" Height="50" Width="50"/>
        <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Background="Blue" Height="50" Width="50"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

user control xaml.cs:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace Ex2
{
    public partial class testUC : UserControl
    {
        public testUC() { InitializeComponent(); }

        public int Row
        {
            get { return (int)GetValue(RowProperty); }
            set { SetValue(RowProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty RowProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Row", typeof(int), typeof(testUC));

        public int Col
        {
            get { return (int)GetValue(ColProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ColProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ColProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Col", typeof(int), typeof(testUC));
    }
}
```

window xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="Ex2.testWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Ex2"
        xmlns:control="clr-namespace:Ex2"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="testWindow" Height="300" Width="300">
    <StackPanel>
        <control:testUC x:Name="grid"
                        Row="{Binding Path=Row, Mode=TwoWay}"
                        Col="{Binding Path=Col, Mode=TwoWay}"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        <Button Click="Button_Click" Margin="40,40,40,40">BUTTON</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

window xaml.cs:

```
using System.Windows;

namespace Ex2
{
    public partial class testWindow : Window
    {
        private testVMText vm;
        public testWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            vm = new testVMText();
            DataContext = vm;
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            vm.Randomize();
        }
    }
}
```

view model:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace Ex2
{
    class testVMText : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public int Row { get; set; }
        public int Col { get; set; }

        public testVMText()
        {

        }
        public void Randomize()
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            Row = rnd.Next(0, 3);
            Col = rnd.Next(0, 3);
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
}
```

My intention was that for each click on the button, a random cell in the grid will be painted in red, but it doesn't to respond at all. When debugging testVMText, the values of Row and Col does seem to change, but it doesn't propagate to testWindow. Why is that?

Comment: I'm not sure what the exact problem is but it's not enough to add the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface, you have to actually notify when a property changes.

Comment: See the previous comment, and marked duplicate for an example of how to do that. If you need more help than that, post a new question, this time making sure to post a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces your problem. There is way too much code above for the question you asked.